# "Import "pygame" could not be resolvedPylance" in VScode

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, importerror, pylance

I am unable to import pygame module.
I have checked the python version and made sure that it matches the one with the interpreter in the env(vitual environment name).
I have tried the existing solutions to similar problems but nothing worked.

I tried in the VS Code terminal:

```
pip install numpy
```

and numpy was successfully installed but then I ran the program and it shows the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

I have tried to add the site-package path to "Python › Analysis: Extra Paths" in VS Code settings.
I also tried:

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

Am I supposed to copy the site-package path from "C:\Users\pande\VScodeWorkspace\env\Lib\site-packages"
or: "C:\Python310\Lib\site-packages"
Note that I am using python 3.11.1 in my env but in the above directory in C drive the folders name is Python310. I have installed Anaconda a few days ago and VS Code just today.
Kindly help I am very new to this. Thank you.

Comment: Is numpy also installed in the virtual environment? If you're using conda, instead of doing pip install numpy, you could try `conda activate your_env` and then `conda install numpy`. Matching python version numbers doesnt necessarily guarantee that the same packages are installed.

Comment: @Chrysophylaxs I have conda installed, but I have created this venv in VS Code and it has nothing to do with conda as far as I know. I did not really need numpy, I just ran the command to check if I could install it and it did get installed but when I ran "import numpy as np" in the code, the error is: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'", but in the case of pygame it is not even being installed.

Comment: @Chrysophylaxs apologies for incorrectly writing numpy in the title, problem is with pygame. Could you please look once again at it?